# Expected value of hypergeometric-like distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Good evening,

I have been trying to figure out how to calculate the expected value of a random variable which is very similar to the hypergeometric distribution. The problem reads as follows:

A population of  animals has had a number  of its members captured, marked and released. Let X be the number of animals it is necessary to recapture (without re-release) in order to obtain  marked animals. Determine E(X).

This seems similar to the hypergeometric distribution, which would fix n and vary m in order describe the event that in n captured animals m had the feature of being marked.

I believe the PMF for this distribution is the same as for the hypergeometric distribution except it is parametrized by n rather than m. It is given by:

$P_X(n) = \frac{\textrm{(ways to select m animals from a marked animals)}*\textrm{(ways to select n-m  remaining animals from b-a unmarked animals)}}{\textrm{ways to select n animals from b total animals}}$
$P_X(n) = \frac{{a \choose m}{{b-a} \choose {n-m}}}{b \choose n}$

Since the PMF only makes sense on the interval m $\leq$ n $\leq$ b, from the definition of expectation:
$E(X) = \sum_{n=m}^{b} n*\frac{{a \choose m}{{b-a} \choose {n-m}}}{b \choose n}$

I don't really know where to go from here. I know arguments can be made for using the linearity of expectations to yield the expectation of the hypergeometric distribution. However, they use the fact that parameter n is fixed.

Does any one have any tips on what process to take to solve this, as well as the name for such a distribution?

EDIT: I believe the name of this distribution is the [negative hypergeometric distribution](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the distribution wrong. You wrote down the probability that exactly $m$ out of $n$ uniformly randomly chosen animals are marked. But you want the probability that you **need** to capture $m$ animals, so you need to exclude the case that you already had $m$ animals before you captured the last one. The probability to capture the $m$-th marked animal on the $n$-th capture is

$$
\frac{\binom a{m-1}\binom{b-a}{n-m}}{\binom b{n-1}}\cdot\frac{a-m+1}{b-n+1}\;,
$$

where the first factor is the probability of capturing exactly $m-1$ marked animals when you capture $n-1$ animals, and the second factor is the probability of capturing a marked animal on the $m$-th capture. However, you can use

$$
\binom a{m-1}(a-m+1)=\binom{a-1}{m-1}a
$$

to rewrite this such that it has the same essential structure as what you had. In any case, the article you've found in the meantime seems to contain all you need to find the expected value.

Comment: I will need to justify the expectation and how I obtained it, on that website I only see the expected value provided but not derived. I figure I will be able to find the derivation of the mean of the NHG to prove E(U) ,where U = the number of unmarked animals, has the mean according to the formula on that website. Then I can define X = U+m and use the linearity of expectation to yield E(X) = E(U) + m.